# Why mock patching works with random but not with np?

Tags: python, numpy, testing, mocking

I have a module where a number of different functions use random numbers or random choices.
I am trying to use mock and patch to inject pre-chosen values in place of these random selections but can't understand an error I am receiving.

In the function I am testing, I use

```
np.random.randint
```

when I use the code

```
from unittest import mock
import random
mocked_random_int = lambda : 7
with mock.patch('np.random.randint', mocked_random_int):
```

I get an error message no module named np.  However, numpy is imported as np and other functions are calling it just fine.

Even more perplexing if I edit the code above to remove the 'np' at the front it does what I want:

```
with mock.patch('random.randint', mocked_random_int):
```

But I want to understand why the code works without the np.  Thank you!

Comment: Does `numpy.random.randint` work? "np" is a variable in your module namespace, not the name of the numpy package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between a module or package name and the variable it is assigned to in any given namespace. A simple import

```
import numpy
```

tells python to check its imported module list, import numpy as necessary, and assign the module to the variable "numpy"

```
import numpy as np
```

is almost the same, except that you assign to a variable "np". Its still the same numpy package, its just that you've aliased it differently.

`mock.patch` will import and patch the module regardless of whether you've already imported it, but you need to give the module name, not your current module's alias to the module.